# How to calculate the propabilty of a specific Y in a poisson regression model in R?

Tags: r, poisson

In my R session, I fitted a poisson regression model on patients in an emergency room like this:

```
fit <- glm(Patients ~ Day + Event, data = df, family = poisson)
```

(`Day` is day of the week; `Event` is "yes"/"no" whether there is a public event in town, like a concert or football match)

Now I can predict Y (the count of patients) for specific `Day` and `Event` like this:

```
predict(fit, data.frame(Day="Tu", Event="yes"), type = "response")
```

which gives me `12.8`. So we can expect about 13 patients on a Tuesday when there is a public event in town.

My question is:
I would like to calculate the propability for Y=16 patients on a "Tuesday", based on my fitted model.
How would I do that?

Comment: Do you mean the probability of _exactly_ 16 patients, or the probability of _at least_ 16 patients?

Comment: Well, both I guess ;) but exactly 16 was my first interest

Comment: Thats what I was looking for, thx!!

Comment: Actually, it's `ppois(16, lambda) - ppois(15, lambda)` for exactly 16, or even easier, `dpois(16, lambda)` and `1 - ppois(15, lambda)` for at least 16.

Comment: Thx again, dude!